Do the medieval sources say anything regarding if God makes up for undeserved suffering in the next world?
Most Rishonim are of the opinion that most people are not subject to hashgachah pratis and can suffer according to the natural way of the world even though their sins don't require such punishment—see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/33779/34188.
That said, is there any discussion in the Rishonim on if HaShem makes such suffering right in the next world somehow or is it just too bad?
(To clarify: This question isn't about the well explored field of the apparent undeserved suffering of the righteous—those that are considered as under hashgachah pratis, the various theories put forth to account for that are dealing with the purposeful targeting of the righteous. In contradistinction, this question pertains to those that suffer precisely because they are outside of the purview of hashgachah pratis and therefore subject to the capricious and random vagaries of the natural order, as the animals are. On that note, and to sharpen the intent of the question, we can enlarge the scope to include the undeserved suffering of animals as well.)

Some of sources there are misqouted. Like ramban holds every punishment is from gzeira. And even other reishonim are specifically reffering to animals not people. The mainstream view is a person can only suffer if he sinned. Unless its yisurim of love. Which the gemara limits to certain cases. However according to the simple understanding of the or hachaim in vayeshev your question stands.

I would suspect that you need to prove that they hold that a life of suffering is inherently something Hashem needs to make up for. Maybe they hold that any life, even a life of suffering, is a gift from Hashem: בכל מדה ומדה שהוא מודד לך הוי מודה לו במאד מאד

@shlomy I'm familiar with the sources and find them to be accurately represented. I used that answer out of convenience. You might be right for Chazal but not for the Rishonim. Or hachaim refers to moral evil only, the Rishonim hold the same for natural evil as well.

@RabbiKaii See Ramban in Sefer hagemul that offers four reasons for engaging in theodicy (all the Rishonim felt the need to). B berachos even has Moshe asking HaShem about it.

@Nahum theodicy in Chazal is generally referring to the righteous suffering. Are the righteous also outside hashgacha pratit according to these Rishonim you reference? Who exactly are in this category of "most" people, or is it purely random? I recommend to clarify these items in the question to get the best possible answers

Also, isn't your last comment also the answer? If these Rishonim engage in theodicy for this category of person, then it would imply they hold that these people who suffer are suffering unjustly and then we can say Hashem must repay them, or not, and therefore Hashem doesn't owe them anything. That's Justice

Also: can someone tell me exactly which Or Hachaim?

@RabbiKaii bereishis 37:21 ויצילהו מידם – פי׳ לפי שהאדם בעל בחירה ורצון ויכול להרוג מי שלא נתחייב מיתה משא״כ חיות רעות לא יפגעו באדם אם לא יתחייב מיתה לשמים, והוא אומרו ויצילהו מידם פי׳ מיד הבחירי ובזה סתר אומרו ונראה מה יהיו חלומותיו וגו׳ כי הבחירה תבטל הדבר ואין ראיה אם יהרגוהו כי שקר דבר.

@RabbiKaii Rambam says one must be developed intellectually to avoid the vagaries of nature, Ramban pegs it to righteousness

@RabbiKaii see eg Ramban Iyov 36:7  ואפילו לא יתחייב מיתה בחטאו אשר חטא,   יהיה משולח ונעזב (ע"פ יש' כז,י) למקרים . . ומפני שרוב העולם מן הכת הזאת האמצעית . .

@RabbiKaii They're dealing with apparent undeserved suffering for those that do have hashgachah pratis, offering various explanations for the targeted suffering of the righteous, my question pertains to those that suffer precisely because they are outside the purview of hashgachah pratis . .

Can you please qoute for me a reishon that says people can suffer without hashgacha pratis?

@Shlomy I quoted Ramban above to Iyov but if you'd like another here's ר' בחיי בראשית י"ח:י"ט
ההשגחה בו להצילו מן המקרים אין זה בכל אדם, ואפילו בישראל, כי אם בצדיקים שבהם, שהקב"ה מציל את הצדיקים מן המקרים ששאר בני אדם נמסרים בידם, ולא יעזוב את חסידיו ולא יגרע מהם עינו, אלא השגחתו בצדיק תמיד לא תפרד ממנו כלל. וזה לשון כי ידעתיו שההשגחה בו ובשאר הצדיקים להצילם ממקרי בני האדם, וזה דעת הרמב"ן בפסוק זה כשתסתכל בו.

This may well tie back to what we discussed a few months back - as to whether a lack of hasgacha = a lack of caring (which is implied by the lack of hasgacha giving permission to kill)
